# How to change color :hover of ant-menu-submenu-arrow in AntD menu component for Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, antd

I'm using Ant Design (antd) components library for Vue.js.
The menu component is quite simple to use: 
https://vue.ant.design/components/menu/

I just want to change the ":hover" color of links (from default blue to red), which is possible by overriding CSS classes.
But is very difficult to me (avoid using ugly workarounds) to change also the color of the "submenu arrow", which remains blue.

[image]

Here is a simple example: 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-antd-sub-menu-arrow-color-34vlx

Anybody has already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
.ant-menu-submenu-title:hover {
    .ant-menu-submenu-arrow::before, .ant-menu-submenu-arrow::after {
        background: red!important;
    }
}
```

But use lang="scss" on your style tag so you can compile scss or just fix my script with css syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this within the `style` tag:

```
.ant-menu-submenu-arrow {
  ::before {
    background: red
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis, but I'm trying to apply the style to the :hover selector